# Error with true and false

Tags: python

Today I am trying to use a boolean expression (True or False) to complete my code; notice that I put the command at `if processor['dictionary'] = True`. It can't run when the code is there. but if it's not there, it can run normally. I can't find the cause of the error that prevents me from running this code, the error being:

`IndentationError: expected an indented block`

Hope you guys can help me.

```
dictionary = {
    "chicken":"chicken two leg animal",
    "fish":"fish is animal that live under water",
    "cow":"cow is big vegetarian animal",
    "space monkey":"monkey live in space",
}

print("how can i help you?")
user_input = raw_input()
print
print("You asked: {}.".format(user_input))

processor = {
    "dictionary":False,
    "dictionary_lookup":[],
}

split = user_input.split(" ")
combos = [' '.join(split[x:y]) for x in range(len(split)) for y in range(len(split)+1) if ' '.join(split[x:y]) != ""]

for w in split:

    w = w.lower()

    if w in dictionary:
        processor["dictionary"] = True
        print w

print combos

# if processor ["dictionary"] = True
response = {}

for item in combos:
    if dictionary.get(item):
        response[item] = "what you were looking for is: {}.".format(dictionary[item])


if not response:
    print("Response: I will get back to you!")
    print


for ind, (k,v) in enumerate(response.iteritems()):
    print("Response {}: {} ({})".format(ind+1, v, k))
    print
```

Comment: Please indent your code by 4 spaces as baseline (you can indent more spaces for code that needs indentation).

Comment: The code after your `if` block is missing or is not indented properly.

Comment: when i remove # before if. the code cant run even after i try to indent it properly. i dont know where else i suppose to fix. althought it seems an ok code. but i want to put the line after # there.

Comment: if processor ["dictionary"] = True should be == because it's testing for equality rather than assignment. (You can actually just omit == True anyway. Don't forget the colon, then indent response={})

Comment: I don't understand how the question could have been asked, because it's about how to do something *that was already correctly done multiple times elsewhere in the same code*.

Answer (score 1):

Python's booleans are **True / False** (with capital letters). true is not equal to True.

Checking for truthness of an object can be done simply

```
if processor['kamus']:
    # your code here
```

This works as same as your code, it just more clear. If you don't put comparison or other instruction in your if statement, Python checks for truthness (True or False, has data or empty)

The **error** you get is because your indentation is wrong, you need to have **4 spaces** after statements (def, if, etc)

Comment: I wonder if the error is rather because of `=` rather than `==` and no colon. Also, I have always thought that for beginners an explicit `== True` is clearer than having it omitted (because it only springs to the mind of someone who already knows the trick/reason behind it).

Comment: I agree on the second part, it is more explicit when True is there. The error is because of the indention, not the `=` or `:`. In case of one of these, the error would be a SyntaxError